# Convert characters to uppercase while Shift key is pressed or/and Caps Lock is enabled in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, keyboard-events

I am making an online keyboard with jQuery and I've encountered a problem.
  My keyboard only displays lower case characters and for the moment I can only type lower case characters while clicking on the letters.
I would like to type upper case characters when the real shift key is pressed by the user.
 Moreover, I would like the online keyboard to type upper case characters when either the virtual caps lock key is enabled or the real caps lock key was pressed by the user.

I have already tried something but it doesn't works at all. Here is what I have already tried.

This is my HTML code with my textarea and my characters divs :

`<textarea id="targetText"></textarea><br />`

`<div class="key by_a"></div>`
   `<div class="key by_z"></div>`

This is the code for my characters (to type the characters) :

```
$('.by_a').val('й');
$('.by_z').val('ц');
```

Here is my code to type the characters in my textarea

```
$('.key').click(function(e){
var tav    = $('#targetText').val(),
    strPos = $('#targetText')[0].selectionStart;
    front  = (tav).substring(0,strPos),
    back   = (tav).substring(strPos,tav.length); 
$('#targetText').keyup(function(e) {
      if (e.keyCode === 16) {
        $('#targetText').val($(this).val().toUpperCase());
}
});
$('#targetText').val(front + $(this).val() + back);
});
```

Thanks in advance for your help. I've tried to be as precise as possible. Here is my [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/steffi13/3n726eqt/)

Answer (score 0):

You would probably need to track all `keydown` events and lock the caps state if either shift is pressed and not yet released or if caps lock is pressed once until it's pressed again.

I assume you could then match this with the state of the virtual capslock/shift button.

So an example of tracking shift could look like this.

```
var shiftPressed = false;
$(document).on('keydown', function(e) {
  if (e.keyCode === 16) shiftPressed = true;
});
$(document).on('keyup', function(e) {
  if (e.keyCode === 16) shiftPressed = false;
});
```

Comment: Thanks for answering @dan_kaufhold . I have tried your solution but it doesn't seems to work. My problem looks more complicated than I could have imagined...

Comment: @BaraKuda sorry, I couldn't help you better. Hope you get it solved